# Git Server Bash and SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, git, bashrc

I want to use Git over SSH with my Linode VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Instructions seem pretty easy, in fact given I had already setup my SSH key etc..

All I had to do was instruct my local repository to send to the server

```
ssh://matt@myvps.com:22/~/mygits/proj1.git
```

Problem is when I do `git push origin master` it just stall, no network activity, no errors, after a few minutes I kill it with Ctrl-C.  I sent along time yesterday try to diagnosis the problem. So on the server I setup a new user `matt2` and copied `authorized_keys` across to `matt2` and tried pushing to `matt2@myvps.com:22` and viola it worked.

What are differences between matt and matt2? Well matt has this in his .bash_profile to ensure an ssh-agent is running (i need this func alot):

```
# Start/Reuse SSH Agent - restart or re-use an existing agent
SSH_AGENT_CACHE=/tmp/ssh_agent_eval_`whoami`
if [ -s "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}" ]
then
    echo "Reusing existing ssh-agent"
    eval `cat "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"`
    # Check that agent still exists
    kill -0 "${SSH_AGENT_PID}" 2>-
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "ssh-agent pid ${SSH_AGENT_PID} no longer running"
        # Looks like the SSH-Agent has died, it'll be restarted below
        rm -f "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"
    fi
fi

if [ ! -f "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}" ]
then
    echo "Starting new ssh-agent"
    touch "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"
    chmod 600 "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"
    ssh-agent >> "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"
    chmod 400 "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"
    eval `cat "${SSH_AGENT_CACHE}"`
    ssh-add
```

So it appears my `.bash_profile` conflicts with the operating of git over SSH. Any suggestions of workarounds?

I don't want to use 2 user accounts, and I want to keep my `.bash_profile.` It would be good if I could edit the .bash_profile and wrap the functionality around `if [ $connectingWith != "git-client" ]` but I doubt such thing exists?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that your `.bashrc` is echoing stuff. Never print anything from `.bashrc` when it's not running on a terminal, as this will break programs that use ssh for automated actions (rsync, git, …).

In fact, you shouldn't do anything from `.bashrc` if it's not running on a terminal. Put this at the beginning of the file:

```
if ! [ -t 1 ]; then return; fi
```

The `.bashrc` file is intended for interactive shells. There's a quirk in bash that makes it load this file for all rsh and ssh logins, regardless of whether they're interactive. This is occasionally useful because it lets you set environment variables for a non-interactive ssh session, but that's completely different thing from interactive setup (prompt, key bindings, aliases and so on). In full generality, `.bashrc` can be two unrelated sections:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  # Stuff for interactive bash shells (defined here as shells running in a terminal).
  # Prompt, key bindings, aliases, terminal settings, …
  # It's ok to print things to the terminal here (e.g. to set the terminal title).
else
  # Environment variables for ssh sessions.
  # Do not print anything here.
fi
```

Side note: for an interactive ssh login, if bash is your login shell, it reads `.bash_profile` but not `.bashrc`. You'll want to source `.bashrc` in your `.bash_profile` (if the shell is interactive).

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. There was something in .bashrc which was causing problems. I didnt see this as this was not executed when SSH in.

Comment: Don't leave us hanging! If you think this could be useful for other people, tell us what in your `.bashrc` was causing the problem and how you solved it. If you think the problem is so specific to your setup that there's no point in having the question and answer on the web, delete them.

Comment: Yes... add here your solution to your question. It might help someone.